# Odd Bump/Normal Map behavior with Texture Nodes - Blender Internal

Tags: texturing, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, normals

So I've run into an issue that is really confusing me.  I'm trying to set up a material that gets bump mapped by a texture that uses nodes and getting odd results.  Here's what I mean:

Bump mapped with normal clouds texture:
[image]

Bump mapped with same settings, but texture that uses nodes:
[image]

That same node texture, but applied to color instead of Normal:
[image]

Hopefully that makes the odd behavior clear.  As you can see, it influences color fine, but if I set it to Normal the entire object looks smoothed out.  The texture in question is just a simple mix of clouds and noise - I've tried both individually and they work fine, but *not when the texture is set to use nodes*.

So, in summary, **what about having the texture use nodes makes it so that it doesn't influence the Normal of the material properly?**

[Here's a link to the .blend](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8649219/weird.blend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output normal data, you need to use the Normal socket on **Output** node. (Be sure to also enable **Normal** setting in *Influence*)

[image]

Comment: Won't that only use the clouds texture though for the normal map?  The Noise node has no output for normal, yet I can set a noise texture to influence Normal just fine if the texture doesn't use nodes.

EDIT:  I just found the Value to Normal node, which solves all the issues I had once I plugged it into the Normal plug that you pointed out.  Thanks for the help!